# Bitmap giving blank screenshot after scratching

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I'v used an open source library to scratch imageview. I'd applied that library on view like that

```
<com.winsontan520.WScratchView
    xmlns:wsv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scratch_view"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

(Note : this view extends to surfaceview).

Then I'd applied image source on that view

```
WScratchView _imageToErase = (WScratchView) findViewById(R.id.scratch_view); 
BitmapFactory.Options options2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options2.inDither = false;
options2.inPurgeable = true;
options2.inInputShareable = true;
options2.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_8888; 
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options2);
_imageToErase.setScratchBitmap(bitmap);
```

Then after setting image source to that view, I'd scratched it a little. after scratching, I'd taken screenshot of that view like that

```
View u = findViewById(R.id.scratch_view);
u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
u.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(u.getDrawingCache());
u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
File mlr = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
.toString() + File.separator + "Colors");
    if (!mlr.exists()) {
            mlr.mkdir();
        }
String extr = mlr.getPath();
String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmm'_Colors.png'")
.format(new Date());
File myPath = new File(extr, fileName);
FileOutputStream fos = null;
 try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b,
        "Screen", "screen");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

taken screenshot from this view is showing a blank view, with or without scratching . I searched a lot but I couldn't know where i'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is because of rendering of `SurfaceView` which is different from any other view.

Try like this:

```
Bitmap  screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(_imageToErase.getWidth(), _imageToErase.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(screenshot);
_imageToErase.draw(canvas); 


File mlr = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
.toString() + File.separator + "Colors");
    if (!mlr.exists()) {
            mlr.mkdir();
        }
String extr = mlr.getPath();
String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmm'_Colors.png'")
.format(new Date());
File myPath = new File(extr, fileName);
FileOutputStream fos = null;
 try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
        screenshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b,
        "Screen", "screen");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your response, it is much appreciated. Mehul, you hadn't taken any screen shot in your code. But i wrote your first three lines and I took screenshot. it is not working.